# Java Script code (Show More - Show Less )

Tags: javascript, php

I have a code that is suppose to display data (Biography) from my database but I am struggling in getting it together, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I am trying to do is to have my page show only let's say 500 character on the bio then when you click show more section it it will extend the content character to the fullest. I also need my box where my content is displayed to be extended as well. Right now when click on show more I get the exact same text twice but not the rest from my database. Than you all for your help and here is my code:

```
<h5>About:</h5>  
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"><!--
    function HideContent(d) {
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
    }
    function ShowContent(d) {
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "list-item";
    }
    function ReverseDisplay(d) {
    if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; }
    else { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }
    }
    //--></script><p><?php echo $row->biography; ?><a href="javascript:ShowContent('uniquename')" backgorund="orange">
    ...show more
    </a></p><br/>
    <a href="javascript:ShowContent('uniquename')" backgorund="orange">

    </a>
    <div id="uniquename" style="display:none;">
    <p><?php echo $row->biography; ?></p>
    <a href="javascript:HideContent('uniquename')">
    show less
    </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you show all content you should also hide first content:

```
<a href="javascript:ShowContent('uniquename'); this.style.display = 'none'">
Show more....
</a>
```

The main difference it's adding `this.style.display = "none"` when `show more` is clicked.

Also it's good to use `onclick` event to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Well, that certainly is happening because you are printing the exact same content inside your `#uniquename` element.

If you want to truncate your text to show just a minor part of it in your first paragraph, you can use PHP's [substr](http://php.net/substr) function. In the following example, I am using a 10 characters limit:

```
<?php
$content = 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';
if (strlen($content) > 10) {
    echo substr($content, 0, 10) . '&hellip;';
} else {
    echo $content;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you are looking for:

```
<body>
    <p id="Content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
    <script>
        (function (){
            var content = document.getElementById("Content").innerHTML;
            var shown;
            var hidden;
            var html;
            if (content.length > 500) {
                shown = content.substring(0, 499);
                hidden = content.substring(500, content.length);
                html = "<div id=\"shown\">" + shown + "<span id=\"showText\" onclick=\"showMore()\" style=\"cursor:pointer\">Show More</span></div><div id=\"hidden\" style=\"display:none;\">" + hidden + "<span id=\"hideText\" onclick=\"showLess()\" style=\"cursor:pointer;display:none;\">Show Less</span></div></div>"
            }
            else {
                shown = content;
                html = "<div id=\"shown\">" + shown + "</div>"
            }
            document.getElementById("Content").innerHTML = html;
        })()
        var showMore = function (){
            document.getElementById("hidden").setAttribute("style", "display:block;");
            document.getElementById("showText").setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
            document.getElementById("hideText").setAttribute("style", "display:block;cursor:pointer;");
        }
        var showLess = function () {
            document.getElementById("hidden").setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
            document.getElementById("showText").setAttribute("style", "display:block;cursor:pointer;");
            document.getElementById("hideText").setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
        }
    </script>    
</body>
```

Comment: Of course, there are about a hundred different ways of going about doing this, but this is the simplest way that I can think of that doesn't use any external libraries, just pure JS and HTML.

Comment: I made the appropriate change and it's working now but if click show more the content scatter with the bottom one. it does not push the table down as well. Any ideas?

Comment: code missing?  could you do a jsfiddle and send the link so I can take a look?  thx.

Comment: I can't add the full code here. how do I send you the full code?

Comment: Just go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and put your code in there, then save it and put the link in a comment, then I can review it.  You won't be able to use your php code, which is why i just put some lorem ipsum dummy text into my example.